# How can I evaluatie this limit at infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I have to evaluate $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( \sqrt{4x-1} - \sqrt{9x} \right),$$ and I cannot use L'Hopital's Rule. At first I thought it should be zero, but I decided to do it analytically.

The first thing I do is multiply and divide by $\sqrt{4x-1} + \sqrt{9x}$ and I get $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{-5x - 1}{\sqrt{4x-1} + \sqrt{9x}}.$$

The problem here is that $-5x-1 \rightarrow - \infty$ and $\sqrt{4x-1} + \sqrt{9x} \rightarrow \infty,$ so I would have something like $\frac{- \infty}{\infty}.$ It is not clear to me how to proceed, so I would like to receive some help to complete the problem.

Comment: Just factor out $\sqrt{x}$ to begin with instead.

Comment: Ok. I see it now. Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 4):

$\sqrt{4x-1}$ is a bit less than $\sqrt{4x}=2\sqrt x$ while
$\sqrt{9x}$ actually is $3\sqrt x$. Thus $\sqrt{4x-1}-\sqrt{9x}<2\sqrt x-3\sqrt x=-\sqrt x $. As $-\sqrt x\to-\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ then
$\sqrt{4x-1}-\sqrt{9x}\to-\infty$ too.

Comment: Note that this way to solve can easily lead to mistakes if applied by not skilled person, thus I suggest to do not solve the limit in this way. It is of course a good way to have a first rought idea about what is going on.

Comment: @gimusi To the contrary, I think this is the best way for this particular limit.

Comment: @egreg Thanks to have given also your point of view but I really think that this way to evaluate is based on a qualitative approach (e.g. "is a bit less") which can lead to mistake if not guided by a great knowledge of the matter. For example for the limit  $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{\sqrt{3x+2}}{x\sqrt{x+6}-\sqrt{x^3+2x}}\right)$ one could conclude that numerator is about $3\sqrt x$ denominator is about $x\sqrt x - x\sqrt x =0$ then limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: @gimusi Not at all. The computation in the answer is not based on “something is about something else”, but on a precise inequality. Since analysis is based on inequalities, this answer is very instructive.

Comment: @gimusi: this method is conceptually simpler and does indeed help in understanding the overall stuff of analysis. I admit that most students however want a procedure / formula to solve problems and this is definitely not a formula based approach. But then formulaic approaches always succeed at the cost of weak conceptual foundation.

Comment: I fully agree with you and this is why l’Hopital rule in general should be avoided, however the standard method here gives in my opinion a clear understanding of what is going on. From this point of view also Taylor’s expansion is a great tool while ratio or root test (as HR) are more susceptible to be used as black box methods.

Answer (score 1):

Next step: Divide numerator and denominator by $x$. Then look at the limit again.

Answer (score 0):

Note that from here you can conclude as follow

$$\frac{-5x - 1}{\sqrt{4x-1} + \sqrt{9x}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt x}\,\frac{-5 - 1/x}{\sqrt{4-1/x} + \sqrt{9}}=\sqrt x\,\frac{-5 - 1/x}{\sqrt{4-1/x} + \sqrt{9}}\to+\infty\cdot\frac{-5}5=-\infty$$